# Loop for printing a statement multiple time in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I'm new here and need your help, I have been assigned a project where I have to model beam calculations on an excel spreadsheet. My problem is that I can't find any command which can help me print a statement 'x' number of times.

E.g.
I ask the user for the number of spans his beam has, and depending on the input, I want this statement(s) to be displayed:

"Enter load for span 1"
 "Enter load for span 2"
 "Enter load for span 3"

And so on.....

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is not that detailed, but I took a shot, and from what I understand you might be looking to have something like this:

[image]

Where you would put a number into B1, and then column C would print out as many statements as requested.

Here's the formula to that:

```
C1=IF(ROW()<=B$1,"Enter load for Span " & ROW(),"")
```

If this is not what you were looking for, show some effort and explain your situation more accurate ;)

Comment: Thanks man, this is exactly what I want but the formula you posted is giving me an error and not working, can you please check this out and get back to me? I am using Excel 2010 btw.

Comment: @SaadPervez yeah, sorry, forgot to translate the `;` to `,`. Should work now.